# How can I limit the scope of a \renewcommand instruction to "table" environments?

Tags: environments, scoping

I want to use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` to adjust the space between the lines in my table. Since I have used matrices all over my paper (and this command also affect the matrices) I want to limit the scope of this command only to apply within `table` environment.

I know I can use another `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}` to change back to the original value after `\end{table}`, however, I would like to know if there is any way to limit the scope of `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Do you want the resetting of `\arraystretch` to apply to *all* `table` environments, or just to specific ones?

Comment: Ideally all the tables, without affecting Matrices.

Comment: Be carefull, you will be surprised to see how many elements use tabulars.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To have the increased value of `\arraystretch` apply to all table-like structures (such as `array`, `tabular`, `tabular*`, `tabularx`, `tabulary`, etc) but only if they occur *inside* a `table` environment, you could issue the following instructions in the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
     \@float{table}}
    {\end@float}
\makeatother
```

(The original definition of `table` is taken straight from `article.cls`; the same definition is given in `report.cls` and `book.cls`.) Note that this redefinition will not affect tabular structures that aren't set up inside `table` environments.

Answer (score 15):

I just figured out if I use `\renewcommand` within the environment itself, the scope would be limited to that environment only. As

```
\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

TABLE CODE


\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why there is no `etoolbox` answer?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment {tabular}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
foo \\ bar \\ baz
\end{tabular}

\[
\begin{matrix}
foo \\ bar \\ baz
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For `table` simply replace `tabular` by `table` as `\AtBeginEnvironment {table}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}}`.

`etoolbox` provides the following environment hooks:

1. `\AtBeginEnvironment {<environment>}{<code>}`
2. `\AtEndEnvironment  {<environment>}{<code>}`
3. `\BeforeBeginEnvironment {<environment>}{<code>}`
4. `\AfterEndEnvironment{<environment>}{<code>}`

Hooks 1 and 2 will be confinining the `<code>` inside the environment. For details, [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net) or `texdoc etoolbox` from command line.

Comment: Harish, `table` not `tabular`.

Comment: @karlkoeller: OK I added a line :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\Tabular\tabular
\let\endTabular\endtabular
\renewcommand\tabular{\begingroup\def\arraystretch{3}\Tabular}
\renewcommand\endtabular{\endTabular\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
foo \\ bar \\ baz
\end{tabular}

\[
\begin{matrix}
foo \\ bar \\ baz
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

and if you want it only for tabulars inside the environment `table` use:

```
\let\Table\table
\let\endTable\endtable
\renewcommand\table{\begingroup\def\arraystretch{3}\Table}
\renewcommand\endtable{\endTable\endgroup}
```

Comment: Won't this method apply to all `tabular` environments, regardless of whether they occur inside or outside of a `table` environment?

Comment: sure, for all _tabulars_ and with the alternative only for those in a `table` environment.

Answer (score 4):

For a more generic solution limiting `\renewcommand{}` inside a scope use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to define the scope. The code

```
\newcommand{\foo}{foo}
\foo
...
\bgroup
    \renewcommand{\foo}{bar}
    \foo
\egroup
...
\foo
```

will yield

> foo... bar... foo